# Spring security using model properties to apply roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC app which I wish to integrate Spring Security with (Spring 3.0.x).

web.xml contains:

```
<context-param>
    <description>Context Configuration locations for Spring XML files</description>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:spring/spring-model.xml
        classpath*:spring/spring-compiler.xml
        classpath*:spring/spring-ui.xml
        classpath*:spring/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <description><![CDATA[
        Loads the root application context of this web app at startup, use 
        contextConfigLocation paramters defined above or by default use "/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml".
        - Note that you need to fall back to Spring's ContextLoaderServlet for
        - J2EE servers that do not follow the Servlet 2.4 initialization order.

        Use WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext) to access it anywhere in the web application, outside of the framework.

        The root context is the parent of all servlet-specific contexts.
        This means that its beans are automatically available in these child contexts,
        both for getBean(name) calls and (external) bean references.
    ]]></description>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <description>Configuration for the Spring MVC webapp servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:spring/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I would like to add role-based security so that users can't access certain parts of the site.

e.g. a user should have the role `CRICKET_USER` to be able to access `http://example.com/sports/cricket` and the role `FOOTBALL_USER` to access `http://example.com/sports/football`.

The URIs in the application retain this hierarchy, so there might be resources such as `http://example.com/sports/football/leagues/premiership` which should similarly require the user to have the role `FOOTBALL_USER`.

I have a controller like so:

```
@Controller("sportsController")
@RequestMapping("/sports/{sportName}")
public class SportsController {

    @RequestMapping("")
    public String index(@PathVariable("sportName") Sport sport, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("sport", sport);
        return "sports/index";
    }

}
```

I've been trying to use the most idiomatic, obvious way to fulfil this requirement, but I'm not sure I've found it yet. I've tried 4 different approaches.

## @PreAuthorize annotation

I've tried to use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole(#sportName.toUpperCase() + '_USER')")` on each @RequestMapping method on that controller (and other controllers which handle URI requests further down the hierarchy. I haven't been able to get that working; no error, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Bad points:

- Doesn't work?
- Method-level annotation, rather than class level, on the `@Controller`. That isn't very DRY. Plus there is the potential for leaving a security hole if more functionality gets added and someone forgets to add the annotation to the new code.
- I can't write a test for it.

## Intercept-url in Spring Security chain

```
<http use-expressions="true">

    <!--  note that the order of these filters are significant -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/sports/**" access="hasRole(#sportName.toUpperCase() + '_USER')" />

    <form-login always-use-default-target="false"
        authentication-failure-url="/login/" default-target-url="/"
        login-page="/login/" login-processing-url="/app/logincheck"/>
    <!-- This action catch the error message and make it available to the view -->
    <anonymous/>
    <http-basic/>
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/app/login/accessdenied"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login/" logout-url="/app/logout"/>
</http>
```

This feels like it should work, would be obvious to other developers as to what it's doing but I've not been successful with this approach. My only pain-point with this approach is not being able to write a test that will flag a problem if something changes down the road.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'hasRole(#sportName.toUpper() + '_USER')'
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:13)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:34)
...
Caused by: 
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E:(pos 17): Method call: Attempted to call method toUpper() on null context object
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:69)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
```

## Standard Filter in the Spring Security chain.

```
public class SportAuthorisationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String pathInfo = httpRequest.getPathInfo();

        /* This assumes that the servlet is coming off the /app/ context and sports are served off /sports/ */
        if (pathInfo.startsWith("/sports/")) {

            String sportName = httpRequest.getPathInfo().split("/")[2];

            List<String> roles = SpringSecurityContext.getRoles();

            if (!roles.contains(sportName.toUpperCase() + "_USER")) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException(SpringSecurityContext.getUsername()
                        + "is  not permitted to access sport " + sportName);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

and:

```
<http use-expressions="true">

    <!--  note that the order of these filters are significant -->

    <!--
      Custom filter for /app/sports/** requests. We wish to restrict access to those resources to users who have the
      {SPORTNAME}_USER role.
    -->
    <custom-filter before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" ref="sportsAuthFilter"/>
    <form-login always-use-default-target="false"
        authentication-failure-url="/login/" default-target-url="/"
        login-page="/login/" login-processing-url="/app/logincheck"/>
    <!-- This action catch the error message and make it available to the view -->
    <anonymous/>
    <http-basic/>
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/app/login/accessdenied"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login/" logout-url="/app/logout"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="sportsAuthFilter" class="com.example.web.controller.security.SportsAuthorisationFilter" />
```

Plus points:

- This works

Bad points:

- No tests.
- Potentially fragile if our application URI structure changes.
- Not obvious to the next guy that comes to change the code.

## Validate in the Formatter implementation used by @PathVariable

```
@Component
public class SportFormatter implements DiscoverableFormatter<Sport> {

@Autowired
private SportService SportService;

public Class<Sport> getTarget() {
    return Sport.class;
}

public String print(Sport sport, Locale locale) {
    if (sport == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return sport.getName();
}

public Sport parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    Sport sport;

    if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
        return new Sport();
    }

    if (NumberUtils.isNumber(text)) {
        sport = sportService.getByPrimaryKey(new Long(text));
    } else {
        Sport example = new Sport();
        example.setName(text);
        sport = sportService.findUnique(example);
    }

    if (sport != null) {
        List<String> roles = SpringSecurityContext.getRoles();

        if (!roles.contains(sportName.toUpperCase() + "_USER")) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException(SpringSecurityContext.getUsername()
                    + "is  not permitted to access sport " + sportName);
        }      
    }

    return sport != null ? sport : new Sport();
    }
}
```

Plus points:

- This works.

Bad points:

- Does this rely on every @RequestMapping annotated method in the controllers having a @PathVariable which retrieves the Sport instance?
- No tests.

Please point out which part of the fine manual I'm missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `#sportName.toUpper()` you need to use something like `#sport.name.toUpper()`, because `#...` variables in `@PreAuthorize` refer to method arguments:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(#sport.name.toUpper() + '_USER')") 
public String index(@PathVariable("sportName") Sport sport, Model model) { ... }
```

**See also:**

- [15.3.1 @Pre and @Post Annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations)

Comment: I'm still missing something there. I have <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" /> in the config, but I don't see the annotation expression getting evaluated; in particular, when I set it to denyAll(), I would expect to get a suitable failure.

Comment: @jabley: Make sure you also have `<global-method-security>` in `...-servlet.xml`, not only in `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: I don't have a ...-servlet.xml. web.xml snippet attached. I have a spring-security.xml and various other spring xml documents. The spring-security.xml document is the only one which contains a <global-method-security/> element. Coding in XML is _such_ a joy.

Comment: @jabley: Then I mean `spring-mvc.xml`.

Comment: woot. That works, thanks. Are you able to help me understand why it has to be defined in one file versus another one?

Comment: Another observation would be to go back to my original question. Annotating each method on a `@Controller` does not seem very DRY.

Comment: Per FAQ: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution as well, use  :

```xml
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Hope it'll help any.

Comment: In fact, i didn't answer correctly but mine could help some peeps that got probleme around this question. This topic his more appropriate : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13071248/1522334