# @PreAuthorize annotation not working spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I found many similar questions but none has solved my problem.
My problem is `ROLE_USER` can access functions of `ROLE_ADMIN`

My spring-security.xml code is following.

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">   

<s:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/helloadmin*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <s:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <s:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</s:http>

<s:authentication-manager>
  <s:authentication-provider>
    <s:user-service>
        <s:user name="asif" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <s:user name="raheel" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />          
    </s:user-service>
  </s:authentication-provider>
</s:authentication-manager>
```

when I add `<s:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>`
my code shows resource not found error and when I remove my code execute successfully but `ROLE_USER` can access `ROLE_ADMIN` functions

My controller function is.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String DeleteAll(ModelMap model, Principal principal ) {

    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User activeUser = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    System.out.println("Active user is "+activeUser.getUsername()+"Authorities are "+activeUser.getAuthorities());
    return "deleteUsers";

}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should have

```xml
<s:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

If you want the `@PreAuthorize` annotations to work.

---

To answer the comment:

It looks like you're missing the `spring-aop` dependency.

If you're using maven you need:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If not you can get the jar from [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cspringframework%7Cspring-aop%7C1.2.6%7Cjar).

Comment: yes i know but when i add <s:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
my code shows resource not found error, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor

Comment: and I am using spring security3.07

Answer (score 34):

If you are using XML Configuration don't forget to add the following attribute:

`<s:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>`

If you are using Java Configuration don't forget to add the following annotation:

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same issue. My problem solved when i moved the below element from applicationContext.xml to *-servlet.xml (my dispatcher's configuration xml).

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

You have to include this element on your **dispatcher's xml NOT on your application's xml**.
[Spring FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context)

Comment: This is definitely the right answer if you don't at least have the global-security-method defined in your servlet's xml config-

Comment: This was the exact issue, +1 for mentioning the Spring FAQ link for explanation.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue working with annotations, the problem was that there was no *@Controller* annotation in my controller.

---

So it seems you need :

- These annotations in your Spring Security configuration :

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebSecurity
  @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
  ```
- Theses annotations in your controller :

  ```
  @Controller
  public class ServiceRS {

      @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
      public void wsAdmin() {
          [...]
      }
  }
  ```

---

Plus if you are still having issues, consider adding this to your log4j2 configuration :

```
    <Logger name="org.springframework.security" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile" />
    </Logger>
```

You will see in logs if your annotations are considered by Spring :

```
TRACE org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource {} [main] Looking for Pre/Post annotations for method 'wsAdmin' on target class '***.ServiceRS' 
DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource {} [main] @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')) found on specific method: public void ***.ServiceRS.wsAdmin() 
DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource {} [main] Caching method [CacheKey[***.ServiceRS; public void ***.ServiceRS.wsAdmin()]] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
```

And obviously you can consider adding breakpoints in corresponding methods in *org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot* to see if a call is done with the condition in your annotation.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Try with @Secured annotation,

Then you'll have

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String DeleteAll(ModelMap model, Principal principal ) {

  ...

}
```

Here's [a detailed blog post about it](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-3-mvc-using-secured.html).

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers have worked for me. I had to go the route of adding security decorators.

Decorators are placed on beans within file `servlet-context.xml`.

First add security schema to the XML namespace:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
...
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```

Then apply the decorator to the implementation of the service bean, like so..

```
<beans:bean id="myService" class="my.service.impl.MyServiceImpl" scope="request">
    <security:intercept-methods>
        <security:protect access="ROLE_USER" method="get*"/>
        <security:protect access="ROLE_ADMIN" method="set*"/>
    </security:intercept-methods>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you :

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This issue will arise when using Servlet 3 with Web Async Support. Spring Security 3.1.4 and below lose their security context once enterting the anonymous method of the `Callable` method.

Upgrading [Spring Security to 3.2.0 RC1](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) will solve your problems.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

put below tag in another spring configuration file, not in spring security configuration file.

I was also getting the same error.

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```