# Restriction for localhost is not working in SpringBoot web security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Restriction for localhost is not working in SpringBoot web security.By commenting the configure method content, URL(http://127.0.0.1:8080/SPPA/runSPPAJob) is working otherwise error comes.

**Code:**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AllowOnlyLocalhostFilter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/SPPA/**").
                access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')").anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

**Web Page Response:**

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon May 29 16:05:46 IST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied
```

**Log:**

```
2017-05-29 16:05:46.482  INFO 3644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/SPPA]   : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-05-29 16:05:46.482 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO 
                    o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/SPPA]-Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 
2017-05-29 16:05:46.485  INFO 3644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-05-29 16:05:46.485 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO 
                    o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started 
2017-05-29 16:05:46.684  INFO 3644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 199 ms
2017-05-29 16:05:46.684 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO 
                    o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 199 ms
```

Comment: the log doesn't help. Can you set in your application.properties logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG and put better logs in the question description?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164876/spring-security-whitelist-ip-range.