# How can I whitelist Domain or IP address in a Rest API application in which we are using springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, whitelist

I'm implementing REST API and we are directly streaming the response using `StreamingResponseBody` of springboot. We are receiving query parameter through JSON and we are sending the database response by directly streaming.

We want to lock down access to the URL to a  particular Domain or set of IP address - how can we achieve this?

Comment: Spring Security enables IP whitelisting. You might find the information contained in this question/answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164876/spring-security-whitelist-ip-range

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java Configuration for Spring Boot Security than you have to use

> ***hasIpAddress()***

in SecurityConfig class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/api/example/**").hasIpAddress("1.1.1.1")
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and()
           .formLogin().permitAll()
           .and()
           .csrf().disable();
    }

    // Rest of Code ...

 }
```